# Java собственный метод addAll() моих объектов класса

Tags: java

Как правильно реализовать метод addAll?
Допустим я создаю клиентов, и лист этих клиентов, но не хочу писать много раз
"clients.add(clien1);" и так далее. Решил создать в классе метод addAllClientsToList(). Думал сделать через VarArgs, тоесть пишу Client.addAllClientsToList(clients, и тут любое количество клиентов, которые заполняют лист, который в первом параметре).
Но тогда java просит, чтоб я вовращал не просто

`List<Client>, а List<Client[]>`

.

```
public static List<Client> addAllClientsToList(ArrayList<Client> clients, Client ... client){

    return clients;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему в последнем случае метод должен возвращать `List<Client[]>`? Просто через `addAll()` добавьте все элементы из массива `client` в список `clients`.

```java
public static List<Client> addAllClientsToList(List<Client> clients, Client ... client) {
    clients.addAll(Arrays.asList(client));
    return clients;
}
```

Здесь в принципе можно ничего не возвращать, если вам не нужно создавать новый объект.

```java
public static void addAllClientsToList(List<Client> clients, Client ... client) {
    clients.addAll(Arrays.asList(client));
}
```

По сути можно просто обойтись `clients.addAll(Arrays.asList(client))`, без написания нового метода.

Comment: или так - `Collections.addAll(clients, client)`

Comment: спасибо! еще такой вопрос? у меня есть Person с id, name, etc. final id и static counter, чтобы при создании каждый объект увеличивал айди самостоятельно. И мой клиент наследуется от персон, как сделать, что при клиенте эти поля тоже выводились toString? ибо выводит только поля клиента(в моем случае телефон и деньги). Тоесть вывожу лист клиентов банка, но выводит просто телефон+сумма, а айди, имя и прочее не выводит, так как это уже персон. Тоесть впринципе я могу получать через getId, но само не выводит

Comment: @ekstra777 не понял, какое `id` у вас должно увеличиваться при создании. Перепишите (ну вы же его уже переопределили) `toString()`, чтобы он выводил нужные поля.

Comment: Ну допустим у меня будут: Employee, Client. При создании любого у меня просто будет айди  Person, а не отдельно для каждого с 1. Тоесть например id 1 - клиент1, id 2 - клиент2, id 3 - сотрудник1, id 4 - клиент3.

Comment: @ekstra777 просто увеличьте `id`. Без кода непонятно, что именно вам нужно. Лучше задайте новый вопрос.